# Matlab wavelet inverse white img

Tags: matlab

I'm using Matlab R2017a to implement integer Haar wavelet transform on images. The Haar transform is done successfully. The inverse transform of the image don't show the reconstructed image but instead it shows a white image. Can you see the code please? I also attaching a screenshot.

Thanks[image]

```
% Load the image of a cameraman.
im = imread('cameraman.tif');
figure,imshow(im);
title('Image');
%%
% Obtain the 2-D Haar transform using the |'integer'| flag.
[a,h,v,d]=haart2(im,1,'integer');
ff = uint8([a,h;v,d]);
figure,imshow(ff);
title('Image2');
%%
% Reconstruct the image using the inverse 2-D Haar transform and view the
% image.
xrec = ihaart2(a,h,v,d,'integer');
figure,imshow(xrec);
title('Decrypted Image');
%imagesc(xrec)
%%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xrec = uint8(ihaart2(a,h,v,d,'integer'));
figure,imshow(xrec);
title('Decrypted Image');
```

Or, alternatively:

```
xrec = ihaart2(a,h,v,d,'integer');
figure,imshow(xrec,[]);
title('Decrypted Image');
```

Your `xrec` variable was in the form of `uint8` values but with `double` as underlying type. This was the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful.